# How can I access directly stateful pods ports on localhost Kubernetes from localhost (for example Cassandra) - what routing is need?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-statefulset, kubernetes-networking

I want to build some testing environment with use Kubernetes on localhost (can be Docker Desktop. minikube, ...). I want to connect my client to 3 instances of Cassandra inside localhost K8s cluster. Cassandra is example it can be same in etcd, redis, ... or any `StatefulSet`.

1. I created `StatefulSet`  with 3 replicas on same ports on localhost Kubernetes.
2. I create `Services` to expose each pod.

What I should do next to route traffic with use three different names `cassandra-0`, `cassandra-1`, `cassandra-2` and same port. This is required by driver - I can not forward individual ports since driver require to run all instances on same port.

So it should be `cassandra-0:9042`, `cassandra-1:9042`, `cassandra-0:9042`.

To shows this I create some drawing to explain it graphically.
[image]

I want achieve red line connection with use `something` ... - I do not know what to use in K8s - maybe services.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should define a node port and send your request to localhost:NodePort

```
  ports: 
   - protocol: TCP 
     port: 8081 
     targetPort: 8080 
     nodePort: 32000
```

Just change your ports so they fit your needs.

If you already created a service with ports exposed, get all endpoints and try turn traffic towards them.

```
kubectl get endpoints -A
```

Comment: Problem is that only one service can be on one nodeport - how to expose multiple services on same port?

Comment: I think that logically this is impossible to expose few services on same port, but a walk around would be a service that 'talks' with other service and all routes go through it.

Comment: I think about Envoy for it or Nginx but not sure if I can route using names - maybe I afraid to much and should try it fast. I think that someone is done it before and can share if it possible.